# How to search hyphenated whole words in PostgreSQL 11.8 in full text search?

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.8. I have query which return result which I'm not expected. I want to compare whole word with OR condition with `key_words` from my categories and sun categories. For that I created this query and it works pretty well for some point, when I faced with words with hyphens. And in this case I have wrong bahaviour, my word `long` matched for `long-sleevedt-shirt` this is not correct

```
        SELECT             
        DISTINCT ca.id
            ,ca.category_name            
            ,cc.key_words AS main_keywords
            ,ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',cc.key_words),to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', :main_search_parial_category)) AS  main_runk

            ,cr_main.sub_category_id AS sub_ctegory_id
                ,crsub.key_words AS sub_keywords
                ,ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',crsub.key_words),to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', :sub_main_search)) AS  sub_runk

            FROM category as ca

        INNER JOIN category_relations as cr_ca_main ON cr_ca_main.sub_category_id != ca.id
        INNER JOIN category_configurations as cc ON cc.category_id_id = ca.id

            INNER JOIN category_relations as cr_main ON cr_main.main_category_id = ca.id
            INNER JOIN category_configurations as crsub ON crsub.category_id_id = cr_main.sub_category_id

            WHERE to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',cc.key_words) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', :main_search_parial_category)

            AND to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',crsub.key_words) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', :sub_main_search)

        ORDER BY
            ca.id
            ,cc.key_words

                ,cr_main.sub_category_id
                    ,crsub.key_words
id |category_name|main_keywords|main_runk|sub_ctegory_id|sub_keywords|sub_runk
1  |Barn         |Barn,barn    |0.2      |2             |t-shirt,kortärmad,tee,shortsleve,piké,pike,långärmadt-shirt,t-shirt,short-sleeved,tee,shortsleve,piké,girl,long-sleevedt-shirt|0.1
```

`sub_runk = 0.1` looks like `long` matched for `long-sleevedt-shirt` key word, but it's not correct I want to whole expression `long-sleevedt-shirt`, 'long' should not macthed to this key word. I tested it separatly

```
    select
                to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish','t-shirt,kortärmad,tee,shortsleve,piké,pike,långärmadt-shirt,t-shirt,short-sleeved,tee,shortsleve,piké,girl,long-sleevedt-shirt') 
                @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Millou|Bunny|long|ears|liten|rainbow|apples|fuchsia') as match;

match = t
```

when I remove `long` I had `f` false, this is correct

and faced with the same result, macth equal true by word `long`, it's not correct should be mathcing if whole expression `long-sleevedt-shirt` equal for some search part.

when I changed `to_tsquery` to `phraseto_tsquery` I faced wth another problem, when I set `long-sleevedt-shirt` to `phraseto_tsquery` result should be true, but I faced with false, why or maybe this is wrong approach ?

```
select
            to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish','t-shirt,kortärmad,tee,shortsleve,piké,pike,långärmadt-shirt,t-shirt,short-sleeved,tee,shortsleve,piké,girl,long-sleevedt-shirt') 
            @@ phraseto_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Millou|Bunny|long-sleevedt-shirt|ears|liten|rainbow|apples|fuchsia') as match;
```

How to set some stric mode or something like that for check only if whole expression match ?

**NOTATION**

One thing about GIN index, it should be changed(or created new index) to new text search configuration

```
create index kw_my_swedish_custom_index on category_configurations
using GIN(to_tsvector('my_swedish', key_words))
```

Comment: ok, only I will add note about should will be changed GIN index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full text parser parses hyphenated words so that the whole word as well as its hyphenated parts become tokens:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('swedish', 'long-sleevedt-shirt');

      alias      |           description           |        token        |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  |        lexemes        
-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------------------
 asciihword      | Hyphenated word, all ASCII      | long-sleevedt-shirt | {swedish_stem} | swedish_stem | {long-sleevedt-shirt}
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | long                | {swedish_stem} | swedish_stem | {long}
 blank           | Space symbols                   | -                   | {}             |              | 
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | sleevedt            | {swedish_stem} | swedish_stem | {sleeved}
 blank           | Space symbols                   | -                   | {}             |              | 
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | shirt               | {swedish_stem} | swedish_stem | {shirt}
(6 rows)
```

One way I can imagine of getting rid of the `hword_asciipart` tokens is to create a text search configuration that does not process them:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish (
   COPY = swedish
);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   DROP MAPPING FOR hword_asciipart;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   DROP MAPPING FOR hword_part;
```

Then use that text search configuration:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('my_swedish','t-shirt,kortärmad,tee,shortsleve,piké,pike,långärmadt-shirt,t-shirt,short-sleeved,tee,shortsleve,piké,girl,long-sleevedt-shirt')
       @@ to_tsquery('my_swedish', 'Millou|Bunny|long|ears|liten|rainbow|apples|fuchsia');
```

Comment: another case with coma. If all my key wrods set contain words divide by coma and some key words complex from some words, like `Bad tröja`, from set `'UV-tröja' => 'uvtröja, uv-tröja, uv-tröjor, uvtröjor, UV-set, Badtröja, Bad tröja'`. How to prepare ts column where it whould be one whole expresssion like `Bad&tröja` or something?

Comment: Define a [thesaurus dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-THESAURUS) that replaces the phrase with a single word (that will be indexed).

Comment: I faced with qustion, what should be in `Dictionary` when I cretae `TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY`, I thought `Dictionary = my_swedish_stem` by faced with error `> ERROR:  text search dictionary "my_swedish_stem" does not exist`. Or better create separate question about thesaurus ?

Comment: I found `SELECT dictname FROM pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict` abd faced with `swedish_stem`, but in my case I use `my_swedish`.  thesaurus dependencies from that or it could be `swedish_stem`?

Comment: Yes, that should be a new question.

Comment: I did it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652659/how-to-correct-cretae-thesaurus-dictionary-for-my-custom-test-search-configurati

Comment: Hi, first of all thatnk you for yours answers. I have simmilar question about special character again, but not hyphen, I want provide the same logic for ampersand, `SELECT * FROM to_tsvector('my_swedish', 'Done by Deer stick&stay tallrik Elphee, grey');` -> `'by':2 'deer':3 'don':1 'elphe':7 'grey':8 'stay':5 'stick':4 'tallrik':6` but need  `stick&stay`, this is possible ?

Comment: If it not possible for globally full text configuration, can I add `stick&stay` in thesaurus dictionary ?

Comment: No, that won't be possible, because that is already split by the parser. You'd have to pre-process the strings, something like `to_tsvector('my_swedish', replace(doc, '&', '-')) @@ to_tsquery('my_swedish`, replace('stick&stay', '&', '-'))`