# How to correctly create thesaurus dictionary for my custom text search configuration

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I use PostgreSQL 11.8. And for Postgres, I use the docker image `postgres:11-alpine`. I want to create a custom full text search dictionary for expressions which are based on some words, like `hello world` should become `hw`.

First of all I have a custom full text search configuration `my_swedish`:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish (
   COPY = swedish
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   DROP MAPPING FOR hword_asciipart;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   DROP MAPPING FOR hword_part;
```

and for this configuration I want to create and use a dictionary. For that I follow the PostgreSQL manual:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY thesaurus_my_swedish (
    TEMPLATE = thesaurus,
    DictFile = thesaurus_my_swedish,
    Dictionary = pg_catalog.swedish_stem
);
```

and am faced with

```
ERROR:  could not open thesaurus file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/thesaurus_my_swedish.ths": No such file or directory
```

I then created the file manually:

```
touch /usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/thesaurus_astro.ths
```

then:

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart
    WITH thesaurus_my_swedish;

 ERROR:  text search configuration "my_swedish" does not exist
```

When I changed it to default `swedish`

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION swedish
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart
    WITH thesaurus_my_swedish;
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR:  text search dictionary "thesaurus_my_swedish" does not exist
```

How to correctly create a thesaurus dictionary for my custom test search configuration?

**UPDATE**
I added in my file `thesaurus_my_swedish.ths` data `hello world : hw` And now

```
SELECT to_tsvector('my_swedish', 'hello world');
```

returned `'hw':1` ,

But what about about othr words ? Because `to_tsvector('my_swedish', 'hello test')` return empty, it should be returned like default swedish

```
SELECT to_tsvector('swedish', 'hello test');
'hello':1 'test':2
```

what is wrong ?

**UPDATE**

I understand, need to add `pg_catalog.swedish_stem` too

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword, asciiword, hword, word
   WITH thesaurus_my_swedish, pg_catalog.swedish_stem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything right, with a few exceptions:

- `thesaurus_my_swedish.ths` should not be empty, but contain rules like this (taken from your example):

  ```
  hello world : hw
  ```
- You should use the new dictionary for all token types that now use `swedish_stem`, that is

  ```
  ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
     ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword, asciiword, hword, word
     WITH thesaurus_my_swedish, swedish_stem;
  ```

This error is mysterious and should not have happened:

```
ERROR:  text search configuration "my_swedish" does not exist
```

Perhaps you connected to the wrong database, or you dropped the configuration again, or it is not on the `search_path` and you have to qualify it with its schema. Use `\dF *.*` in `psql` to list all existing configurations.

Of course you have to create the dictionary before you can use it in a text search configuration.

Don't modify the configurations in `pg_catalog`, such modifications would be lost after an upgrade.

Comment: You ritgh, but one think, `to_tsvector('my_swedish', 'hello test')` returned empty result. I updated question

Comment: I realized I have made a mistake in my `ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION` statement; fixed. You have to restart PostgreSQL after you edit `thesaurus_my_swedish.ths`. By the way, if you change the file, you have to rebuild all indexes and update all columns that rely on the mapping.

Comment: But I have many expression with `och` - `Öronmuffar och vant set`, `Fuskpäls och shearling` and others

Comment: I want to add in `thesaurus_my_swedish.ths` this data `hello och world : how`, but after that, when my trigger try to prepared ts vector thrown exception - `SQLSTATE[F0000]: Config file error:7 ERROR:  thesaurus sample word "och" i     s a stop word (rule 1)                                                          HINT:  Use "?" to represent a stop word within a sample phrase.                 CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function category_configurations_ts_trigger() line 3 at      assignment` Becasue `/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/swedish.stop` contain och. Separate question for this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659380/how-to-correct-fill-thesaurus-dictionary-if-i-need-to-use-some-word-which-could