# how to correct fill thesaurus dictionary if I need to use some word which could be present in stop words

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.8. I cretaed `thesaurus_my_swedish` and use it for my `my_swedish`

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish (
   COPY = swedish
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   DROP MAPPING FOR hword_asciipart;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
   DROP MAPPING FOR hword_part;

CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY thesaurus_my_swedish (
     TEMPLATE = thesaurus,
     DictFile = thesaurus_my_swedish,
     Dictionary = pg_catalog.swedish_stem
 );

 ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_swedish
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword, asciiword, hword, word
    WITH thesaurus_my_swedish, pg_catalog.swedish_stem;
```

But after I fill `/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/thesaurus_my_swedish.ths`

```
hello och world : hw
Öronmuffar och vant set : Öronmuffar och vant set
```

I faced with error when my trigger after save configuration key words try to generate and save ts vector for it

```
CREATE FUNCTION category_configurations_ts_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.common_fts :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('my_swedish', coalesce(new.key_words,'')), 'A');      
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON category_configurations FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION category_configurations_ts_trigger()

  SQLSTATE[F0000]: Config file error: 7 ERROR:  thesaurus sample word "och" i  
  s a stop word (rule 1)                                                       
  HINT:  Use "?" to represent a stop word within a sample phrase.              
  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function category_configurations_ts_trigger() line 3 at   
  assignment
```

because my dictionary contain expression with `och` which present in

```
 cat /usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/swedish.stop
```

how to correct fill  thesaurus dictionary if I need to use some word which could be present in stop words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-THESAURUS) says it clearly:

> Specific stop words recognized by the subdictionary cannot be specified; instead use `?` to mark the location where any stop word can appear. For example, assuming that `a` and `the` are stop words according to the subdictionary:
>
> ```
> ? one ? two : swsw
> ```
>
> matches `a one the two` and `the one a two`; both would be replaced by `swsw`.

So use the rule

```
Öronmuffar ? vant set : Öronmuffar och vant set
```